# FullCalendar v4 add onclick eventListener to events displayed on eventLimitClick popover

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, popover, fullcalendar-4

I have a custom development with FullCalendar v4 js and I'm encountering a problem with `eventLimitClick` method.

When I click on it I want all events displayed inside popover to have a custom `onclick` eventListener for me to display aditional information of this current event in another custom popup.

This is my method so far:

```
eventLimitClick : function(info){
    info.segs.forEach(function(seg){
        seg.el.querySelector('div.fc-content').addEventListener('click', function(event){
            console.log('event definition', event);
        });
    });
    return "popover";
}
```

But this is adding the listener to the elements I already see in my calendar. I also tried with `hiddenSegs` instead of segs but it's not working.

So is there any way to achieve this without having to create a custom popup with all the events?

** EDIT ** [included code]

calendar object

```
     {
        locale : 'en',
        plugins : ['dayGrid','timeGrid','list','interaction'],
        header : {
            left : 'prev,next today',
            center : 'title',
            right : 'dayGridWeek, dayGridMonth, dayGridDay'
        },
        allDaySlot : false,
        aspectRatio : 1.8,
        displayEventTime : false,
        editable : false,
        navLinks : true,
        eventLimit : true,
        views : {
            dayGridMonth : {
                eventLimit : 2
            }
        },
        events : this.eventLIST,
        datesRender : this.calendarviewRender,
        eventClick : this.calendareventClick,
        eventRender : this.calendareventRender
     }
```

`datesRender`, `eventClick` and `eventRender` functions:

```
calendarviewRender = (info) => {
    //set current and end dates
    this.endDate = info.view.activeEnd;
    this.currentDate = info.view.activeStart;
    //retrieve fresh event/task info
    this.refreshCalendar();
}
calendareventClick = (info) => {
    this.info = {id : info.event.id,
                 tipo : info.event.extendedProps.tipo,
                 tipoObj : info.event.extendedProps.tipoObj,
                 isClosed : info.event.extendedProps.isClosed && info.event.extendedProps.isClosed !== null ? (info.event.extendedProps.isClosed === 'false' ? false : true) : false,
                 campos : info.event.extendedProps.lCamposInfo};
    //allow second button
    this.info.displaysecondbutton = !this.info.isClosed && this.info.tipoObj === 'Task';
    //allow popup display
    this.allowpopup = true;
    info.jsEvent.preventDefault();
}
calendareventRender = (info) => {       
    let html = "<i class='fa fa-" + info.event.extendedProps.icon + " fa-lg'></i>";
    info.el.querySelector('div.fc-content').style.cssText = 'height: 100%;';
    //if month view apply padding
    if(info.view.type.includes('dayGrid')) info.el.querySelector('div.fc-content').classList.add('slds-p-around_x-small');
    //center elements
    info.el.querySelector('div.fc-content').classList.add('slds-align_absolute-center');
    //append icon
    info.el.querySelector('div.fc-content').innerHTML = html;
}
```

I also removed `eventLimitClick`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need this? fullCalendar already has an `eventClick` callback (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick) which will fire automatically whenever any event is clicked on, regardless of whether it's inside the eventLimit popover or not.

Comment: @ADyson yes but my issue is that `eventClick` is not working when I click on popover events. So I tried a different approach

Comment: Really? I don't see a problem with using eventClick there. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/KKKjOwe . Perhaps you did something else which stopped it working? I would suggest fixing that issue instead of trying to attempt a fragile workaround. If you need helping fixing such an issue, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code so we can understand the cause.

Comment: @ADyson I'm working with it on `lightning-web-components` and is FullCalendar v4. And I'm not getting any erros on console. I'll try something slightly easier like an `alert` and check if that works

Comment: @ADyson I also updated my question with source code. Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: I updated the CodePen using as close to your code as I can with vanilla FullCalendar (I don't know what lightning web components is or how it works), and I still can't find a problem with using "eventClick". https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/KKKjOwe

Comment: @ADyson I already tried that but no further response. Lightning web components are Salesforce based. And maybe that's the problem with this but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments i see you were working with lightning-web-components.

I was facing same issue as you when working with LWC on salesforce.

I was able to solve this by editing main.js in daygrid package and add delay when Popover was getting hidden.

Here is snippet of code

```
function Popover(options) {
        var _this = this;
        this.isHidden = true;
        this.margin = 10; // the space required between the popover and the edges of the scroll container
        // Triggered when the user clicks *anywhere* in the document, for the autoHide feature
        this.documentMousedown = function (ev) {
            if (_this.el && !_this.el.contains(ev.target)) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    _this.hide();
                }, 1000);
            }
        };
        this.options = options;
    }
```

functions starts in line 100 of main.js.
I was using Fullcalendar v4